# write a variable before all other component executes

Tags: c#, ssis

Hi i am reading an xml file. In this file i have many tables. I am using 3 table of that. And one of those table contains date of creation. I need that date in another table to perform some operations. So i used varible to store the value of date and then i am using that value in the another table. But the value is not written. I know it's post execution but i found some code to write a variable. as below

```
 private void WriteVariable(String varName, Object varValue)
     {
         IDTSVariables100 vars = null;
          VariableDispenser.LockForWrite(varName);
          VariableDispenser.GetVariables(out vars);
          try
           {
             vars[varName].Value = varValue;
           }
          catch (Exception ex)
         {

           }
          finally
         {
           vars.Unlock();
          }
       }
```

Please suggets me something

Comment: Where are you calling this method?

Comment: in  Input0_ProcessInputRow to assign the value of one of it's row to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would deliver the output flow required to a Recordset Destination, storing the rows in a Variable (type = Object).  Then in a downstream For Each Loop Container, you can loop over the rows and assign the date column to a Variable.  Within that container I would add whatever components need to reference the date.

Comment: Can you elaborate more..?
Adding For each loop will increase the execution time. And i don't want to do that. That Solution was the first came in my mind but it will consume atleast a cycle run. But i am looking for something that update the varible right after it get the value.
Thanks!

Comment: How much will it increase the execution time?  I expect it would be trivial.  If you are not happy with the result, try one of the alternative solutions.